cout << !(5 > 7) && 2 > 3; True or false?
Выполнял тест c++ и попалось такое задание, логично если подумать то результат должен быть False, я проверил в трех компиляторах и завис. Объясните пожалуйста, почему false? Приоритет у ! выше, но он справа налево; а у остальных операторов в данном примере приоритет ниже и слева направо.

Опишите в вопросе ваше логику рассуждения, почему не должно быт false? Желательно пошагово.

false не должно быть, если мы не присваиваем выражение переменной, а сразу выводим через cout. А если присваиваем, то ничего никуда не теряется и получается false.

Смотрим приоритеты...
Ну, понятно, 5>7 в скобках.
! перебивает &&.   cout << (!(5 > 7)) && 2 > 3;
Сравнение перебивает && : cout << ((!(5 > 7)) && (2 > 3);
Оператор << перебивает &&: (cout << ((!(5 > 7))) && (2 > 3);
Все понятно?
Вычисляем 5>7 - false, его отрицание  - true, что и выводим. Ну, а результат вывода сравниваем с 2>3 и никуда его не выводим...

Спасибо, все теперь стало ясно), я не подумал что << тоже оператор.

@LoK-DoK, хорошо запмните -- мировой запас скобок не ограничен

Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга.
Не хватило пару баллов)
@avp запомнил)
